# Could you replace the word "transaction" with a more a simple word but still the same meaning

Tags: word-meaning

> When you apply for an original DL/ID card, you must present an acceptable birth date/legal presence document and provide your social security number (SSN). Depending on the birth date/legal presence document you present, your California DL/ID card may expire on the same date as your legal presence document. If the name on your birth date/legal presence document is different from the name on your DL/ID card application, you must also bring an acceptable true full name document. Your fingerprint, signature, and picture will also be taken (Refer to the "Application Requirements for a Basic Class C Driver License" section). For any other DL/ID card **transaction**, you must present photo

I even have my doubts if the choose of the word transaction in the text is a correct choise. Because it has to do with business, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> Because it has to do with business, doesn't it?

*Transaction* is a term often used in service and retail contexts.

In this context it is an all-encompassing noun that refers to any issue a person might have that requires action by one of the organization's service representatives.

A purchase of a loaf of bread at a convenience store can be called a "transaction" when it is perceived in terms of the exchange between the customer and the business. The business computer system would track "retail transactions".

As to whether there are simpler words, possibly not, when one considers that *transaction* is *the* standard generic name for such person-organization interactions. One might substitute "issue" but that word can have connotations of discontent and disgruntlement, which would raise red flags at the DMV.  Soporific blandness is a virtue in a bureaucracy.